# Indexed URL is very low comparing submitted URL in google

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors, crawl-rate

I have 84 URL in my website. Till 2 weeks back all the URL is indexed in Google. I have verified it in Google webmaster tools.

But it was slightly decreased day by day. Now Google webmaster tools shows like 4 URL is indexed.

Is there is any idea to make Google re crawl the website again.?

Comment: You can use the [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) tool to stimulate crawling and see if there's any issue accessing your pages and resources. It might be however that Google found your content to be thin or otherwise deficient, so you should take some time to review it (note that individual SEO site reviews is off-topic here so we won't be able to do that for you).

Comment: This has been happening to many sites since spring and may have to do with Content Quality, Spam Tactics, Linking, News/Trend Value, etc., just to name a few of the updates. As well, Panda 4.2 is running and will not be complete until sometime in 2016. Of late, it seems like sites that appear legitimate are being hit because Google is tightening the requirements. It may also be a simple refresh that can take time. It can also simply be the recent fluctuations we have seen in the SERPs. There is no way of really knowing.